# How to use .RemoveAll in here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, removeall

Simple question here, but this has been killing me trying to get this to work...

I have a class, called `Taxonomy`.  There is a property called, `WebName`, I get a list of `Taxonomy` classes, and would like to use `.RemoveAll` to remove any of the Taxonomy's within the list with the `WebName.ToLower()` equal to either `"n/a"` or `"other"`.  `WebName` property is of type string.

This is what I tried so far:

```
List<Taxonomy> theNeighborhoods = new List<Taxonomy>();
Taxonomy aNeighborhood = GetCachedNeighborhoodTaxonomy(); // Returns the Parent Taxonomy

theNeighborhoods = aNeighborhood.Children.ToList(); // This gives me a list of Taxonomy classes
```

How can I change `theNeighborhoods` List to only select values that do not have "n/a" or "other" in the `WebName` property of each `Taxonomy`?

```
theNeighborhoods = aNeighborhood.Children.ToList().RemoveAll(a => a.WebName.ToLower() == "n/a" || a.WebName.ToLower() == "other").ToList();
```

The above code gives me error, something like `int` has no extension `ToList`  How to do this with `.RemoveAll`?

Comment: RemoveAll doesn't return a list -- it returns the number of elements removed from the list.

Comment: @pmcoltrane - Ouch, ok, figured this was what I needed.  How to filter this list here than?

Comment: @SolomonClosson I was in the middle of typing an answer when I noticed that several others have already provided decent solutions.

Comment: Ok, Thanks so much you guys... guess I understood `.RemoveAll` wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do one of two things.  First you could use a where from LINQ:

```
theNeighborhoods = aNeighborhood.Children.Where(a => a.WebName.ToLower() != "n/a" && a.WebName.ToLower() != "other").ToList();
```

Alternatively you could call RemoveAll after getting the list, like so:

```
theNeighborhoods = aNeighborhood.Children.ToList();
theNeighborhoods.RemoveAll(a => a.WebName.ToLower() == "n/a" || a.WebName.ToLower() == "other").ToList();
```

RemoveAll returns an int that represents how many items were removed.  That is why you got the error you did.  I suggest looking up the documentation on RemoveAll.

Comment: There are two problems here. 1) Your first solution where condition is wrong. It should be `&&` not `||`. 2)You're calling `ToList` twice in first solution(Granted that's op's code, you need to point it out).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Good catch. Editing to fix that.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
theNeighborhoods = aNeighborhood
                   .Children
                   .Where(a => a.WebName.ToLower() != "n/a" &&
                               a.WebName.ToLower() != "other")
                   .ToList();
```

Your code doesn't work because `RemoveAll` returns an `int` not the `List<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`.

Also worth noting that you're calling `ToList` twice, `ToList` isn't free. It involves creation of new array and copying the items. So avoid redundant use of `ToList`.

Comment: This is the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try only:

```
aNeighborhood.Children.ToList().RemoveAll(a => a.WebName.ToLower() == "n/a" || a.WebName.ToLower() == "other");
```

You cannot write ToList() because RemoveAll return the number of elements removed (int).

Comment: Nope, this is useless. You create list, remove items from it and ignore it. You never assigned it to `theNeighborhoods` field

Comment: Oh yes, I've forgot ToList() before RemoveAll ! Thanks Sriram!